# Ansible not able to fetch nginx status on linux hosts

Tags: ansible, devops

I am new & just started learning ansible. I installed ansible on ubuntu server & edited the /etc/ansible/hosts file with the IP's of my nodes. But ansible is not showing the status of the nginx service.

[image]

Seems that the ad-hoc command doesn't do anything.

Comment: you need to use shell or command module and then pass `sudo systemctl status nginx` command as argument to the shell or command module. Otherwise you can use service module to check status of the service.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) methods for Ansible, rather than using `sudo` (that's most likely reason for the ad-hoc command to be "stuck").

Comment: @KrishnaReddy -- the default module in ad-hoc mode is `command`, so it is generally sufficient to just pass the `-a "some-command-here"` as argument.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: To follow up on the privilege escalation comment, using shell/command for this is a bad practice. See [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html)

Comment: Since you are not getting any output, there must be an issue with the ssh connection, could you share command output with `-vvv` flag via pastebin for example? **PS!** make sure to redact any sensitive information beforehand.

Comment: At the very least please test with correct privilege escalation (if not moving to service_facts...) => `ansible Demo --become -a "systemctl status nginx"`. As already reported above, the problem is most likely `sudo` awaiting for some sort of input (e.g. a password) or not being configured correctly (see the link already provided in second comment).